# Removing notification using String tag and int id?

Tags: android

I'd like to put a notification in the notification tray. It's for a multiplayer game, and I want to notify a user when it's their turn to make a move. They can participate in multiple games at once, and I'll send one notification per game when/if it's their move. Each game has a unique ID, so I wanted to send notifications like:

```
int TYPE_NOTIF_YOUR_TURN = 0;
String gameId1 = "abc";
String gameId2 = "xyz";

mgr.notify(gameId1, TYPE_NOTIF_YOUR_TURN, notification);
mgr.notify(gameId2, TYPE_NOTIF_YOUR_TURN, notification);
```

Now if I need to cancel one of the notifications, I can look up using the tag (in my case the gameId)?:

```
// only remove the second notification:
mgr.cancel(gameId2, TYPE_NOTIF_YOUR_TURN);
```

Is that how it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's exactly how it works.

<s>On a side note though, I would make the String tags unique to your app package. Example...</s>

```
String gameId1 = "com.mycompany.mypackage.gameid.abc";
String gameId2 = "com.mycompany.mypackage.gameid.xyz";
```

The reasoning behind this is that when cancelling, the string and the int must match to identify the notification to cancel. Many apps are likely to use int values of 1, 2, 3 etc. So the simpler the string tag, the more likely another app (using simple tags) might accidentally cancel one of your notifications.

In general it seems fairly unlikely but unique tags will avoid it. It also seems likely that this would be recommended practice though I haven't looked into it much.

Comment: The tags only need to be unique to your package name.

Comment: When showing a notification (and cancelling it) the `tag` and `id` combination used needs to be unique withing app. The `tag` can also be null, and it's wrong to consider that other app might accidentally cancel other notifications. Docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Why we use `tag` even we can make notification unique by `id`?